# Are these summaries of the history of the Digital World of the Cyber Sleuth games correct?

Tags: digimon-cyber-sleuth-series

Is [this description](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/12977241/8/A-Game-of-Cat-and-Cat) of a game's Digital World, talking about the Cyber Sleuth games, correct?

> One new game takes the theory that Digimon and the Digital World always existed, and computers are merely the newest gateway; shamans and occultists could previously summon Digimon.

This [reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/digimon/comments/kfbaog/the_digital_world/gg7k1ot/) seems to indicate that's possibly right:

> in the video Game digimon cyber sleuth, the digital world always existed and the evolution of human technology allowed them to travel there.

---

Are both of those descriptions accurate, if the first description is talking about the Cyber Sleuth games? Did pre-"modern day" humans summon Digimon in the Cyber Sleuth games, but human-travel into the Digital World was only unlocked by "modern" technology?